# Airbnb's ES6 style guide recommendation about functions

Tags: javascript

Referring to section 7.1 in the style guide:

```
// bad
function foo() {
}

// good
const foo = function bar() {
};
```

I can't seem to understand what exactly is wrong with the first statement ?
How is it bad ? 
(fyi .. I do understand the difference that the first declaration is hoisted and the 'const' do not get hoisted. What I do not understand is being hoisted bad ?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the first. The second is quite longer, but throws when you try to overwrite the `foo` variable (you never assign to functions, right?)

Comment: If multiple scripts are embedded, it may happen that theyve got the same name. Thats why using const is better in that case

Comment: Despite all the good and bad things about this code style, this question is primarily opinion based.

Comment: They do have a lot of weirdness in their [style guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript), luckily it's just a guide, and you don't have to follow everything.

Comment: You ask "What I do not understand is being hoisted bad ?" and the4 style guide section you're referring to says, "Function declarations are hoisted, which means that it’s easy - too easy - to reference the function before it is defined in the file. This harms readability and maintainability." that seems pretty clear that (in the opinion of the style guide authors) hoisting is indeed bad. What further explanation are you looking for? Do you want a specific example that demonstrates how "referenc[ing] the function before it is defined in the file" can lead to mistakes or reduced readability?

Comment: (If yes, it's not clear to me why you didn't also include that passage in the question itself. If that *is* what you want, maybe you should edit it into your question.) (Also, I'm assuming you're using https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#functions--declarations -- if you're using a different version of their style guide that doesn't include that explanation, you might also want to link to it in your question.)

Answer (score 2):

AirBnB has already explained why they consider function declarations hosting a bad thing [here](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#functions--declarations):

> 7.1 Use named function expressions instead of function declarations.
>
> Why? Function declarations are hoisted, which means that it’s easy -
> too easy - to reference the function before it is defined in the file.
> This harms readability and maintainability. If you find that a
> function’s definition is large or complex enough that it is
> interfering with understanding the rest of the file, then perhaps it’s
> time to extract it to its own module! Don’t forget to name the
> expression - anonymous functions can make it harder to locate the
> problem in an Error's call stack.

Comment: Then I really don't know what answer will satisfy you. After all, you are using **their** linter's settings and asking "why did they use this option", so there is no better explanation than from the authors. Of course, it doesn't have to make any sense, like any other code style guide on the Internet.

Comment: actually Bergi's answer above was quiet satisfactory

Comment: ohh.. a negative point .. did I hurt your feelings  @mdziekon

Comment: Um... why? I don't get it.